# Edit a large file containing latitude and longitude data to become valid JSON

Tags: json, shell

I have the following [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Elkfox/Australian-Postcode-Data/master/au_postcodes.json) which I want to use as test data for a project. The only data I need from the file is the latitude longitude data in Location objects.

I managed to delete all unwanted data from the file using the following command:

```
sed -i '' '/pattern/d' ./locations.json
```

Now I am stuck trying to remove the unwanted `,` character on each longitude line. How can I quickly do this using shell script?

```
[
    {
        "latitude":-35.2777,
        "longitude":149.1189,
    },
    {
        "latitude":-35.3049,
        "longitude":149.1412,
    },
    {
        "latitude":-35.1627,
        "longitude":150.6907,
    },
    \\ and so on
]
```

What I am trying to do is replace this patters `"longitude":\d+.\d+,` with `"longitude":\d+.\d+`

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** is the right tool for processing JSON data:

```
jq 'map({latitude, longitude})' ./locations.json
```

The output (shortened):

```
[
  {
    "latitude": -35.2777,
    "longitude": 149.1189
  },
  {
    "latitude": -35.3049,
    "longitude": 149.1412
  },
  {
    "latitude": -35.1627,
    "longitude": 150.6907
  },
  {
    "latitude": -35.028,
    "longitude": 150.5501
  },
  {
    "latitude": -35.1333,
    "longitude": 150.7
  },
....
]
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Comment: Is it possible to do this in-place?

Comment: `jq 'map({latitude, longitude})' ./locations.json > tmp_json && mv tmp_json ./locations.json`